# STL sort not working

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

```
for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
{
  values.clear();

  scanf("%d %d %d", &values[0], &values[1], &values[2]);
  printf("%d %d %d\n", values[0], values[1], values[2]);
  sort(values.begin(), values.end());
  printf("%d %d %d\n", values[0], values[1], values[2]);

  printf("Case %d: %d\n", i + 1, values[1]);
}
```

I have that small snippet. I enter "1200 1500 1800" and it is supposed to give me the middle value - 1500. However, it's outputting 1200, the smallest value.

What I do is I use STL's sort() to sort the vector and then I print values[1], which is the middle value.

However, the sort() doesn't seem to be working at all, the printed vector before and after is the same thing.

I declare my vector with:

```
vector<int> values (3);
```

I tried to declare it with `vector<int> values;` and then `push_back(0)` three times and it.

I'm wondering why it doesn't work the first way, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
values.clear();
```

This clears `values` so that it contains no elements any more. Attempting to access any elements will result in undefined behaviour and the `std::sort` will simply sort the empty sequence of numbers.

The definition of `a.clear()` where `a` is a sequence container is:

> Destroys all elements in `a`. Invalidates all references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of `a` and may invalidate the past-the-end iterator.
>   *post*: `a.empty()` returns true

Answer (score 6):

Your program has **Undefined Behavior**.

In order to fix it, just remove this line:

```
values.clear();
```

What the above line does, in fact, is to **erase all elements from the vector**. Then, this line:

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &values[0], &values[1], &values[2]);
                   ^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^
```

Will try to access non-existing elements. Unlike `operator []` for associative containers, `operator []` for vectors won't create any new element. Thus, the expressions `values[0]`, `values[1]`, and `values[2]` are all attempts to access non-existing elements.

Per Table 101 of the C++11 Standard:

> *Expression*: `a[n]`
>
> *Return type*: reference; `const_reference` for constant `a`
>
> *Operational semantics*: **`*(a.begin() + n)`**

This means that by doing this:

```
values[0]
```

You are actually doing this:

```
*(values.begin() + 0)
```

The call to `values.begin()` here returns an iterator to the first element in the array. Since there is no element in the vector (§ 23.2.1/6), a call to `values.begin()` is equivalent to a call to `values.end()`:

> `begin()` returns an iterator referring to the first element in the container. `end()` returns an iterator which
>   is the past-the-end value for the container. If the container is empty, then `begin() == end()`;

Therefore, `values[0]` in your case is actually equivalent to this:

```
*(values.end() + 0)
```

Which is in turn equivalent to this:

```
*(values.end())
```

In other words, you are dereferencing an iterator that points to a position beyond the last element in the container. This is Undefined Behavior, and the same applies of course to `values[1]` and `values[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think  **__median** function in **< algorithm >** header is easier.

```
med = __median(a, b, c);
```

Comment: You mean `std::nth_element`.  There is no function like `__median` in the (standard part of the) standard library.

Answer (score 0):

When you clear the `vector` you are setting the size to 0. The `scanf` line will ususally not crash since the `vector` will usually have preallocated some storage where the read values are stored. The result is that when you call `sort`, `begin()` and `end()` will be equal.

You can try either reading the values into temporaries, or calling `resize(3)` before reading the vaules.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to clear out the actual existing elements with `values.clear();` is actually removing them from the vector completely. This has the effect of making `begin()` and `end()` equal, causing the sort to have no effect (and the input where you take the address of the various elements to have undefined behavior).

I think what you really wanted to do was make sure that there aren't too many elements in the vector, so instead of `clear` use `resize`: `values.resize(3)` which will have the effect of removing excess elements or increasing the size of the vector to three if it's currently smaller.